# Invalid method Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute::isAllowedForRuleCondition

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, eav, entity-manager

I am getting an issue on Magento 2.2 when trying to create promotion rule. This error occurs sometimes and the error disappears if run Magento upgrade command. But it comes again sometime.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**The Issue:**

My team recently ran into this on `v2.3.1` of Magento Community, and it appears that you may have an attribute with an `attribute_model` of type `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute` when the system is *actually* expecting type `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute`

For reference, you can check out the line of code where that error is being thrown. For me it's here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3.1/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/Model/Rule/Condition/Product.php#L70-L71

You'll see a comment on the type of what that variable is (expected to be):

`/* @var $attribute \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute */`

**The Solution:**

Well, *my* solution was to update that `attribute_model` value in the `eav_attribute` and/or `eav_entity_type` tables directly - you'll see some others have done this in the Magento issue linked to in Rafael's answer. After this, you'll want to make sure you run a reindex and clear cache. Hope that helps!

> Just a note: if you continue to run into this issue, it may be the case that you have some code (maybe custom or a 3rd party module) that is adding/updating an attribute and setting that `attribute_model` value incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

It's a [native issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12176), but you can try these options:

1 - Try disabling third-party extensions (e.g. Mgt_DeveloperToolbar).

2 - Try to refresh or disable the cache before.

3 - As a temporary fix you can do that:

Override the file `vendor/magento/module-rule/Model/Condition/Product/AbstractProduct.php` override the method `Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Product\AbstractProduct::loadAttributeOptions()`, and change the line:

```
if (!$attribute->isAllowedForRuleCondition() || !$attribute->getDataUsingMethod($this->_isUsedForRuleProperty))
```

to

```
if (!$attribute->getDataUsingMethod($this->_isUsedForRuleProperty) ||!$attribute->isAllowedForRuleCondition())
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be full page cache error

**Flush Magento Cache** or redeploy the code by below commands

1. setup upgrade:                       php bin/magento se:up
2. Static content deploy:               php bin/magento s:s:d -f
3. Cache flush:                         php bin/magento c:f
4. Re-index:                            php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Answer (score 0):

Its actually an easy fix - Just close any other Magento admin windows in your browser and refresh cache. Then press ctrl + F5 to force refresh your browser session and try again.

In my case, I had one Magento admin window open with Mirakl listings setup, and it wasnt acknowledging the cache refresh that I was doing in a separate window.

Everything was going fine setting up new listings until I added new dropdown options to an existing attribute in a new window, which was used in some product listings in the other window.

Best stick to one window, and don't share logins :D